# I need to play a video when Iam touching on that video . And need to pause when video in list scrolls out

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

In my app I just added RecyclerView that list contains multiple videos . I need to play video when Iam touching on that video . And need to pause when video scrolls out .

```
mVideoPlayer_1.addMediaPlayerListener(new SimpleMainThreadMediaPlayerListener(){
   @Override
   public void onVideoPreparedMainThread() {
    // We hide the cover when video is prepared. Playback is about to start
    mVideoCover.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }

   @Override
   public void onVideoStoppedMainThread() {
   // We show the cover when video is stopped
    mVideoCover.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }

   @Override
   public void onVideoCompletionMainThread() {
       // We show the cover when video is completed
       mVideoCover.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
});

 mVideoPlayerManager.playNewVideo(null, mVideoPlayer_1, "http:\\url_to_you_video_1_source");
```

I need to pause the currently playing video when it scrolls out .

Comment: please provide all that relevant code you have, what you've tried so far, and where your problem lies specifically

Answer (score 0):

Use `onClickListener` in RecyclerviewAdapter and `onScrollListener` in your Activity

Comment: okay . but how will i identify that videoview scrolls out , and stop it

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener